# Add rows to a Data GridView when Listbox option is selected VB.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, listbox

I am looking to create an Options Administration page for a website I am working on. I need to update a GridView with SQL data depending on what option is selected in a ListBox.

The code below is what I have so far for the ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged. The Gridview will have 2 columns, Code and Text. There could be multiple results for the SQL query. Any help would be much appreciated :-)

```
Dim SC As SqlConnection
    Dim NSC As New SqlCommand

    SC = New SqlConnection()
    NSC = New SqlCommand()

    SC.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AsbestosConnectionString").ConnectionString
    SC.Open()

    NSC.Connection = SC
    NSC.CommandText = ("SELECT CODE_ID, CODE_DESN FROM ASB_XREF (nolock) WHERE CODE_TYPE = @P1 ORDER BY CODE_DESN")
    NSC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", lst_options.SelectedItem)

    Dim DR As SqlDataReader = NSC.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: try debugging your code and check what values are you getting at `NSC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", lst_options.SelectedItem)`. Also you should use `SelectedValue` in place of `SelectedItem` to get the values

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have made the change in my code. I hadn't run the code yet as I am trying to get my head around the passing of the data into a GridView.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem.

```
NSC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", lst_options.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have made the change in my code. I hadn't run the code yet as I am trying to get my head around the passing of the data into a GridView.